# Argo CD error="server.secretkey is missing"

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

Argocd failed to load after restart. In the argocd server logs I see that `server.secretkey` is missing but I didn't see where it is declared and I think it should be generated by argo server

the server logs:

```
time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="Starting configmap/secret informers" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="Configmap/secret informer synced" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="Initialized server signature" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="Initialized admin password" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=warning msg="Unable to parse updated settings: server.secretkey is missing" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="Starting configmap/secret informers" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="configmap informer cancelled" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=warning msg="Unable to parse updated settings: server.secretkey is missing" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="secrets informer cancelled" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="Configmap/secret informer synced" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="Starting configmap/secret informers" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="configmap informer cancelled" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="Configmap/secret informer synced" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="secrets informer cancelled" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="Creating client app (argo-cd)" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="argocd v2.1.2+7af9dfb serving on port 8080 (url: https://argo.jgjhg.hgg.tech, tls: false, namespace: argocd, sso: true)" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="0xc000d7f380 subscribed to settings updates" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="Starting rbac config informer" time="2023-01-08T06:48:55Z" level=info msg="RBAC ConfigMap 'argocd-rbac-cm' added" time="2023-01-08T06:49:22Z" level=warning msg="Unable to parse updated settings: server.secretkey is missing"
**time="2023-01-08T06:50:37Z" level=warning msg="Unable to parse updated settings: server.secretkey is missing"
**time="2023-01-08T06:51:22Z" level=warning msg="Unable to parse updated settings: server.secretkey is missing" time="2023-01-08T06:51:49Z" level=warning msg="Unable to parse updated settings: server.secretkey is missing" time="2023-01-08T06:52:22Z" level=warning msg="Unable to parse updated settings: server.secretkey is missing" time="2023-01-08T06:58:55Z" level=info msg="Alloc=14201 TotalAlloc=64664 Sys=74065 NumGC=13 Goroutines=139" time="2023-01-08T07:03:36Z" level=info msg="received unary call /version.VersionService/Version" grpc.method=Version grpc.request.claims=null grpc.request.content= grpc.service=version.VersionService grpc.start_time="2023-01-08T07:03:36Z" span.kind=server system=grpc time="2023-01-08T07:03:36Z" level=error msg="finished unary call with code Unknown" **error="server.secretkey is missing" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.method=Version **grpc.service=version.VersionService grpc.start_time="2023-01-08T07:03:36Z" grpc.time_ms=20.524 span.kind=server system=grpc
```

I am using argo helm 3.21.0

argo should restart and run without problems

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by simply restarting the argocd server.

Here's what I did to fix it:

```
kubectl rollout restart deploy/argocd-server
```

Answer (score 2):

The `argocd-secret` is created only during the initial installation. Within the [Helm chart](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/blob/8ee317128d31b75a07d263bffb07b57cb80a69f5/charts/argo-cd/templates/argocd-configs/argocd-secret.yaml) you see that the condition to create it is defined at the top `{{- if .Values.configs.secret.createSecret }}`. However I presume that this secret got deleted somehow, and there's no ArgoCD component that "manages" this secret. You could recreate the secret, with other values such as [admin user credentials](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/blob/8ee317128d31b75a07d263bffb07b57cb80a69f5/charts/argo-cd/values.yaml#L1919).

However re-generating the secret can be also achieved by re-applying your Helm Chart which will only install the missing/changed components: `helm upgrade RELEASE-NAME argo/argo-cd`. Once the Secret exists, you'll need to restart/delete the ArgoCD-Server pod, which will inject the values such as (those will be populated only after the said argocd-sever restart!):

```
data:
  admin.password: JDJhJDEwJHl4cmhWRE5zRGQuOVdSMVRKNkE2VWVlM24uaXhmRmROblVZVkhQTzdqYVA3LmdmcWdEc2JT
  admin.passwordMtime: MjAyMy0wMS0wOVQwODoyMDo0OFo=
  server.secretkey: R1hzK0hDSk1oTVdqT3grK0J6SVJmdzhMUXpqNzUwN0ZSUmVQeXZDdXRBYz0=
  tls.crt: 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
  tls.key: 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
```